# How to call variable of the upper class in inner class?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I have to call a variable defined at the upper class to the inner class.

Code

```
class outer:
  def __init__(self):
    self.Out = 'out'
    self.In = self.inner()
  class inner:
    def __init__(self):
      self.InOut = outer.Out

c = outer()
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __init__
AttributeError: type object 'outer' has no attribute 'Out'
```

Comment: `Out` is an instance attribute of `outer`. `inner` does not have an instance of `outer` to get the attribute from: You're trying to read it from the class, which doesn't have it. You could pass it into `inner`'s init method. Not really clear what you're aiming for, or why you have one class inside another at all.

Comment: Also classes should start with a capital letter. Attributes should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To create a new instance of the `Inner class`, you should prepend with the `Outer` class name, i.e `Outer.Inner()`.
- You should define the `Inner` class before referencing it.
- in `Outer.__init__`, you can pass the container object into the created instance of `Inner class`, i.e `Outer.Inner(self)`, which will be passed as argument `outer` in `Inner.__init__` method.

```py
class Outer:
  class Inner:
    def __init__(self, outer):
      self.in_out = outer._out
      print(self.in_out)

  def __init__(self):
    self._out = 'out'
    self._in = Outer.Inner(self)

c = Outer()
```

Comment: Here, the last self references Outer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `outer.Out` is an attempt to access a class attribute (in class context) while that attribute is initiated in instance context (`self.Out`). That's 2 different contexts.

If you still need to define a nested class which have access to parent class instance - pass the `Outer` instance to inner `Inner` constructor as reference:

```
class Outer:
  class Inner:
    def __init__(self, parent):
      self.InOut = 'inner ' + parent.Out

  def __init__(self):
    self.Out = 'out'
    self.In = Outer.Inner(self)


c = Outer()
print(c.In.InOut)   # inner out
```

Comment: Can be solved by the above way. Though I don't need to define the nested class, I still have the same error. Does that mean the inner class on which the code I posted should move to the upper side to the outer class?

Comment: @NokiLee, it should work. What's the python version that you are on?

Comment: This is Python 3.7.4. Sorry I forgot to write parent when I didn't use the nested class.

Comment: @Samha', you are wrong - `c.In.InOut` is not evident to be stated as "static context"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest You're right, I got confused because of using variables in CAPS.